# MonkeyRunner/AndroidViewClient basic script not working

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I have a pretty basic script where I intend for the application to drag 3 times, and then touch a button. The application drags three times perfectly, but then get's an error when I add in the touch code.

Code:

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
device.drag((120, 220), (300, 220), 1, 20)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
device.drag((120, 220), (300, 220), 1, 20)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
device.drag((120, 220), (300, 220), 1, 20)
temp = device.findViewWithText('Lesson 1')
temp.touch()
```

Error:

```
line 34, in <module>
    device, serialno = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
TypeError: 'instance' object is not iterable
```

New Code:

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
temp = device.findViewWithText('Lesson')
```

New Error:

```
    temp = device.findViewWithText('Audiobooks')
AttributeError: 'com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice' object has no attribute 'findViewWithText'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra ')' at the end:

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
```

I guess you mean

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
```

### New code

The problem with your new code

```
temp = device.findViewWithText('Lesson')
```

is that `findViewWithText()` is a method in `ViewClient` class not in `MokeyDevice` as the error tells you:

```
AttributeError: 'com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice' object has no attribute 'findViewWithText'
```

So the correct code is:

```
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
temp = vc.findViewWithText('Lesson')
```

Take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/tree/master/AndroidViewClient/examples) and you'll have all your questions answered.